# JavaFx application under Ubuntu 22.04 window twitches briefly

Tags: java, ubuntu-22.04

Under Ubuntu 22.04 there is a strange behavior of a JavaFx application. When a new window or message box is opened, the window and message box twitches briefly. Also, an open menu detaches from the window when it is moved.

What can be done about this?

See webm: https://webm.red/view/pKM7.webm

```
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Application extends javafx.application.Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu menu = new Menu("Menu");
        MenuItem menuItem1 = new MenuItem("MenuItem 1");
        MenuItem menuItem2 = new MenuItem("MenuItem 2");
        menuBar.getMenus().add(menu);
        menu.getItems().addAll(menuItem1, menuItem2);
        menuBar.setPrefHeight(30d);
        Button button = new Button("Messagebox");
        button.prefWidth(100d);
        button.prefHeight(30d);
        button.setOnAction(actionEvent -> {
            Alert alert = new Alert(Alert.AlertType.INFORMATION);
            alert.setTitle("Messagebox");
            alert.setHeaderText(null);
            alert.setContentText("Message...");
            alert.showAndWait();
        });
        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(button);
        stackPane.setPadding(new Insets(50));
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        vbox.getChildren().add(menuBar);
        vbox.getChildren().add(stackPane);
        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox);
        stage.setWidth(500);
        stage.setHeight(400);
        stage.setTitle("Hello!");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

On Lubuntu 22.04 and on Windows 10 the application behaves normally.

Comment: Seems that you should open a bug with the JavaFX developers/maintainers.